# How can i know if my vertex and fragment shader is executing in a nvidia GPU (using GLSL)

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is it possible to tell if my shaders are running in my nvidia graphics card and the performance of each shader.

Comment: If your OpenGL implementation is provided by NVIDIA, then there's a reasonable chance that the shaders will be executed on an NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: So i don't need to add some special function or something, i mean the shaders will run by default on the nvidia GPU?

Comment: Why are you asking specifically about the shaders. If your whole OpenGL program uses the NVIDIA card, then yes, your shaders will also run on that card.

Comment: Sorry i'm new in the subject, well i understand that the OpenGL program just use the CPU but the shaders are the ones that run on the GPU, and according to what i've read and understood, for example, to draw a triangle you need to crate a buffer on the GPU and there is where you send your vertex data to be proceced by all the stages of the rendering pipeline, and thats why i'm asking if the shaders run by default on the nvidia gpu if i have one.

Comment: @IchiJi: When I said "reasonable chance", I was being *sarcastic*. Of course shaders are run on the GPU; that's *what they're for*. If you have an NVIDIA card, and you're using the NVIDIA OpenGL implementation, then shaders will be run on the NVIDIA GPU. If you have an AMD card, and you're using the AMD OpenGL implementation, then shaders will be run on the AMD GPU.